# Print a table without metatables in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

Is it possible to print a table without using metatables in Lua?

In Roberto's book *Programming in Lua*, he mentions "The function `print` always calls `tostring` to format its output". However, if I override `tostring` in my table, then I get the following results:

```
> a = {}
> a.tostring = function() return "Lua is cool" end
> print(a)
table: 0x24038c0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print a table"? Do you mean print each key and value in a table? Do you want to print keys and values in subtables as well? There is no "standard" way of printing a table in Lua, so the answer depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Get some serializer and print its output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can NOT be done without metatables.

---

> The function `print` always calls `tostring` to format its output.

You misunderstood this. Here, `tostring` is the function [`tostring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-tostring), not a field of a table. So what it means is that `print(t)` will call `print(tosstring(t))`, that's it.

For tables, `tostring(t)` will then find if it has a metamethod `__tostring`, and uses that as the result. So eventually, you still need a metatable.

```
local t = {}
local mt = {__tostring = function() return "Hello Lua" end}
setmetatable(t, mt)
print(t)
```

Comment: `__tostring` can be a field in `t` if you call `setmetatable(t,t)`.